# object change notification compute engine instance

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, bucket

So what I'm trying to accomplish is opening a notification channel between my compute engine instance and a bucket within the same project. I went through the process of getting the external IP of the instance on the allowed domains list using webmaster. However, when I execute the command to open the channel

```
gsutil notification watchbucket https://<IP address here> gs://query-request
```

I get the error message stating that the domain is not authorized to watch the bucket and that it needs to be whitelisted even though I've already added it to the allowed domains. Are compute engine instances not able to watch buckets or is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: You added the IP to both webmaster tools *and* the cloud console? The IP should show up at console.developers.google.com under "APIs & auth" -> "Push"

Comment: Yes, I added the IP to webmaster tools and I added it to the allowed domains on the push tab in the developer console

Comment: Can you try it with a domain name instead of an IP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize by service account. See on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Notification_Types) under the "Configuring gsutil to Use the Service Account" section how to do it.